# amazon AWS SES: Email fails using SDK but works on console. Says Email address is not verified

Tags: java, email, amazon-web-services

I am trying to send emails using java AWS email SES SDK. I have verified couple of emails and tested them in console which work very well.

Now, when I try sending mails over java SDK, it fails by saying "Email address is not verified". I am using SDK version 1.6.0. The documentation says emails are case sensitive. Since I have my emails all in lowercase (same as while connecting using the SDK) which works on the console, I don’t think that should be problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you connected to the same end point as in the console ? Sounds like you may be connected to a different region.

Basically, use the same region where you have verified your sender's email address.

Comment: yeah i also thought that. So, i tried adding region using             Region REGION = Region.getRegion(Regions.US_WEST_2);
            sesClient.setRegion(REGION); my console region is oregon viz us west 2. But, it said that region does not has any email service available.

Comment: What user/email are sending your emails as on the API?  Is it registered as a known sender?  Are you using SES credentials (they are different from the regular AIM credentials)?

Comment: Well i added emails and verified them. After that i used console to send test emails to/from them as both to and from requires verified emails. it did worked in console. But, with sdk it says that email is not verified. maybe the region problem or sdk's bug.

Comment: Don't think it's an SDK bug, this is a very basic operation.  Check the credentials you are using to send email from your code.

Comment: yeah. There is no problem with credentials. I have used exactly the one it created. Also, it does not reports any security key issue.

Comment: well i just solved it. It was a weird region issue. My console was in oregon but sdk said that oregon didn’t had any email service. So, i moved my console to east coast and verified my emails to that region console. I updated my region to be this new east coast and it worked then.

Comment: I've got the same error but using USEast1 shouldn't be the suggested solution.

Comment: @timmah.faase the suggested solution is basically use the same region where you have verified your sender. Or your case is different?

Comment: I can't connect to the USWest2 Endpoint via the API at all. I've contacted AWS for input. Same code works for USEast1.